# Sum of First five numbers in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am learing assembly language on x86 platform and made a simple program to add first five number and print values on to screen.Below is my code

```
section .data
x db "value=%d" ,10,0
tc db "value is =%d" ,10,0
section .text
global main
extern printf

main:
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx,0
well_done:
add ecx ,ebx
push ebx
 push x

call printf
add esp,4
pop ebx
inc ebx


cmp ebx ,6

jnz well_done

push ecx
push tc
call printf
add esp,8
ret
```

But the output I am getting is below

```
value=1
value=2
value=3
value=4
value=5
value is =0
```

Can anybody tell me where I am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ECX` register is caller-saved in the [CDECL](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ratdevz/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.cbl.win.doc%2Ftopics%2Frpsubw29.htm) calling convention, which means that if you want to preserve its value across function calls you (the caller) have to save and restore it yourself.

Comment: Definitely. Most probably, `printf` is trashing your `ECX`. You could either `push ecx` or use a register other than `EAX`, `ECX` or `EDX`. See **[x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)** on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks @Michael for your response ,code wise how I improve ,I mean what can be modified to get result

Comment: It's a bit "busy", maybe finish the numerical/registers part, pushing everything onto the stack, including the total. Then call the print function as required to plonk everything onscreen. Then you avoid registers being corrupted during the calculation part.

Comment: Thanks @Powerslave changing ECX to EBP worked out well for me,Just one query did all four EAX ,EBX,EDX and ECX are used by printf as caller savee ,I am getting some problem understanding the caller-saved concept

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: The documentation I linked to lists `EAX`, `ECX`, and `EDX`. It means that you can't rely on _any_ of those registers to retain their value across function call. As for what the solution is, you can push `ECX` on the stack before calling `printf`, and pop it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @Michael again,We did as you suggested and it worked out well but only thing which confusing me here ,call prinf routine at time will be using only register(for saving) but rest of register would be free.Am I right here??

Comment: The rest of the registers can be considered to be _callee-saved_; that is, the callee (in this case `printf`) is free to use modify those registers but has to restore them before returning to the caller.